# Binding equivalent to an x:Bind in a ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, controltemplate, winui-3

How can I duplicate the effect of the following binding:

```xaml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind viewmodels:ShellViewModel.TheShellViewModel.CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

with a Binding in WinUI 3 (v1.1.5)?

`TheShellViewModel` is a `static ObservableProperty` in the `ShellViewModel` class that refers to the singleton instance of the `ShellViewModel` class in the application. `CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize` is an `ObservableProperty` in that instance.

Using a `DataContext` or creating a property in the code-behind class enables access with a `{Binding ...}` but neither of these is available in a `ControlTemplate` (`x:Bind` works there if set up correctly).

I thought

```xaml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TheShellViewModel.CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize, Source=viewmodels:ShellViewModel}"/>
```

or something similar would work, but it doesn't. What is the proper form for `Path` and `Source` in this case, please?

**==== Additional Code (added) ====**

```c#
public partial class ShellViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    public static ShellViewModel TheShellViewModel { get; private set; }

    public ShellViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, INavigationViewService navigationViewService)
    {
        // .ctor code
        TheShellViewModel = this;
    }

    private double _CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize;
    public double CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize
    {
        get => _CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize;
        set => SetProperty(ref _CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize, value);
    }
}
```

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns:models="using:PFSI.ViewModels">
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="CaptionButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border>
            <!-- Layout and VisualState infomation -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="cbText" 
                Text="{x:Bind viewmodels:ShellViewModel.TheShellViewModel.CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

To make the `x:Bind` on `cbText` work:

> The `{x:Bind}` markup extension depends on code generation, so it needs a code-behind file containing a constructor that calls `InitializeComponent` (to initialize the generated code). You re-use the resource dictionary by instantiating its type (so that `InitializeComponent` is called) instead of referencing its filename.

(see: [Data Binding in Depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)) which is easily done (not entirely shown, here). `Binding` in code is straightforward using `OnApplyTemplate()` on a class derived from `Button`. Neither of these solutions are as clean and obvious as using some sort of out-of-scope reference for a XAML `Binding`.

I feel certain I've done this before but, in a Senior moment, I can't remember how. I ultimately went with the `OnApplyTemplate()` solution in the interests of moving on (and `OnApplyTemplate()` has some other benefits, too).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you share more code about how you are implementing each class?

Comment: See above for additional information. And thanks for looking.

Comment: I posted an answer but still can't understand why you need to make ``ShellViewModel`` static. It'd be simpler if you just use it as regular class.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't use `x:Static` in UWP. One way to do this might be accessing the static class via a property.

This works:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ShellViewModel CodeBehindShellViewModel { get => ShellViewModel.TheShellViewModel; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="Miscellaneous.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:Miscellaneous.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style
                x:Key="CustomButton"
                TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border>
                                <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="cbText"
                                    Foreground="SkyBlue"
                                    Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=CodeBehindShellViewModel.CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" />
        <Button
            Command="{x:Bind viewmodels:ShellViewModel.TheShellViewModel.DoublePathSizeCommand}"
            Content="Double" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace Miscellaneous.ViewModels;

public partial class ShellViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    // You need to instantiate this.
    // In this case, I just instantiated it here.
    public static ShellViewModel TheShellViewModel { get; private set; } = new();

    public ShellViewModel(/*INavigationService navigationService, INavigationViewService navigationViewService*/)
    {
        // .ctor code
        TheShellViewModel = this;
        CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize = 123.45;
    }

    // Assuming you are using the "CommunityToolkit.Mvvm",
    // you can use the "ObservableProperty" attribute and
    // auto-generate a "CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize" property.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private double _currentCaptionButtonPathSize;
    //public double CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize
    //{
    //    get => _CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize;
    //    set => SetProperty(ref _CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize, value);
    //}

    // This is just a test code to check if the "CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize" works.
    // The "RelayCommand" will auto-generate a "DoublePathSizeCommand" command for you.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void DoublePathSize() => CurrentCaptionButtonPathSize *= 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct when coded directly in a style or `Page` definition. But how can I use a `{Binding...}` (not `{x:Bind...}`) in a `ControlTemplate`?